# Check if DbSet<T> is empty

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, generics, entity-framework-core

I am working on a method to seed an EF Core database from json. As such, I have a series of methods that function as desired like below for each entity (`FilterList` and `Language` are the two example entities). These methods are all identical except for the name, dbset property name, and two instances of the entity type.

```
private static void SeedFilterLists(FilterListsDbContext context)
{
    if (context.FilterLists.Any()) return;
    var types = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<FilterList>>(
        File.ReadAllText(SeedDirectory + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + typeof(FilterList).Name + ".json"));
    context.AddRange(types);
    context.SaveChanges();
}

private static void SeedLanguages(FilterListsDbContext context)
{
    if (context.Languages.Any()) return;
    var types = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Language>>(
        File.ReadAllText(SeedDirectory + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + typeof(Language).Name + ".json"));
    context.AddRange(types);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I'd like to replace all of this duplication with a single generic method. I have tried something like below, but it is not quite there. I am not sure how to reference the DbSet property. What can I use in place of the question mark in the commented line, or is there a better alternative to seeing if the table of generic type is empty?

```
//TODO: fix generic method to remove duplication of entity-specific methods
private static void Seed<T>(DbContext context)
{
    //if (context.?.Any()) return;
    var rows = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(
        File.ReadAllText(SeedDirectory + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + typeof(T).Name + ".json"));
    context.AddRange(rows);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

My DbContext for reference:

```
public class FilterListsDbContext : DbContext
{
    ...
    public DbSet<FilterList> FilterLists { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Language> Languages { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
private static void SeedLanguages(FilterListsDbContext context)
{
    Seed<Language>(context, c => c.Languages);
}

private static void Seed<T>(FilterListsDbContext context, Func<FilterListsDbContext, DbSet<T>> setFunc) where T : class
{
    var set = setFunc(context);
    if (set.Any()) return;
}
```

---

or just use the `DbContext.Set<T>` [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696521(v=vs.113).aspx):

```
private static void Seed<T>(DbContext context) where T : class
{
    var set = context.Set<T>();
    if (set.Any()) return;
}
```

It exists in EF6 so I hope it does in EF Core.

Comment: Perfect! That worked! You helped me save a bunch of duplication. :) https://github.com/collinbarrett/FilterLists/commit/2355cba86bcbd0340cdcf519d9b42ae3f373ab90

Comment: the only thing I had to modify, using your second approach, was adding `where T : class` to avoid the reference type error